# Difference between Joomla 1.5 Joomla 1.6 and joomla 1.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

What is the difference in versions of Joomla CMS i.e. Joomla 1.5, Joomla 1.6 and joomla 1.7 ?

Comment: I think this is not the right place to ask this question. Anyway check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla)

Comment: As others have said - this isn't really the proper forum for such an broad, open-ended question.  The differences are vast between 1.5 & 1.6 - www.joomla.org - look there for more information.

Comment: This would be the perfect question for a StackOverflow site for Joomla such as http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Main Differences between 1.5 and 1.6**

Refined Access Control Layer
One-click upgrades of core CMS

J1.6 to 1.7 is very much an incremental upgrade - lots of small refinements to user workflow.

J1.8 will be called J2.5 - but don't ask why.

Comment: It will be called J2.5 because it's the next long term release. 2.6 and 2.7 will be short term releases and the 3.5 will be long term again. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

Features of joomla 1.7 are :-

1) unlimited accesss levels

2) user can be assigned to user groups and user groupes can than be assignd to access levels

3) templates: administrator templates and website templates

4)  templates styles

5) search engine optimization

Answer (score 2):

[image: Joomla Versions]

- Joomla 1.5 - Long term support (LTS) version
- Joomla 1.6 - Short term support (STS) version. Adds a full access control list functionality plus, user-defined category hierarchy, and admin interface improvements.
- Joomla 1.7 - Short term support (STS) version. Adds enhanced security and improved migration tools.

[image: Joomla Release Cycle]

Answer (score 1):

And one more thing to add:

## J1.6+ has capability to have unlimited (and nested) Categories.

And a total shift towards more developer friendliness. Developers can easily customize the extensions and have more control over the code. Some new API included in version 1.6+ and also there is more focus on security and stability of whole system. The best thing is that, its one-click upgrade like you see in wordpress.

So above are the differences that you wont see in Joomla 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 are the only supported version as all 1.6 and 1.7 users are recommened to migrate to 2.5.

A multitude of things have been changed and added since 1.5 such as Multi user access, backend interface, extension code structure, increase in speed and much more.

Even though 2.5 is the latest version and has many more features, lot's of people have stuck with Joomla 1.5 as they are used to the backend interface and coding style. I myself like to stick to Joomla 1.5 unless the site I'm developing requires multi user access in which case I will go for 2.5.

In the end its a matter of choice and both versions are good and secure.

Joomla 3.0 will come out in September and even then, lots of people will stick to older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The features of Joomla 1.7 in compare with joomla 1.5 and 1.6 are:

1) One click upgrade

2) Multi language Improvements

3) Refined Access Control Layer

4) Faster release cycles

Answer (score 0):

main difference is xml structure is change.

joomla 1.5 xml file and joomla 1.6 or 1.7 or 2.5 xml file are different structured .

Answer (score -1):

1.5 and 1.7 are long term support for many years 
joomla 1.6 is a intermediate version and d'ont have support yet!

Comment: Good point - 1.5 is long term support, as will be 1.8/2.5. However 1.7 is NOT long term support and 1.6 is not only outdated it is already End of Life.

Comment: 1.7 is not a long term support version. 2.5 is the next long term supported version.